# How to map each character in a string to a value?

Tags: python, variables

If I had this set of *items* like this:

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
```

How would I go about assigning them to each character from this:

```
string = 'python'
```

To this:

```
(p, y, t, h, o, n) = (15, 24, 19, 7, 14, 13)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That seems like a horrible idea. What are you trying to accomplish? This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: It seems that you tried to create some *mapping* from each *character* to its position/index?   Is that the case?  Or some real *variable*?  Not clear!

Comment: @Superfudge - there're many good answers that try to help you.  Please review and ask questions, or check/accept the ones that really solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to establish a mapping between two tuples from a mapping between two elements, you can try to use comprehensions and convert it to tuple, like this example:

```py
# a mapping on elements, not necessarily lambda
f = lambda x: x*2
# a tuple that you want to map from
t1 = (1,2,3)
# comprehension ( a generator object )
t2 = (f(x) for x in t1)
# convert it into a tuple. Output: (2, 4, 6)
print(tuple(t2))
```

Converting a string to a tuple can be done in a similar manner:

```py
s = "Hello"
t = (x for x in s)
print(tuple(t)) # output ('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only logic to use is to assign numbers to each alphabet serially, then we can use a simply loop over letters in the `string` and get there index from a string which stores all the alphabets.

```py
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

string = "python"

print([x for x in string], [letters.index(i) for i in string ])
```

#### OUTPUT

```py
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'] [15, 24, 19, 7, 14, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the builtin [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function, and do the assignment using the [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function to update the current variable in use locally.

```
>>> string = 'python'
>>> toinclude = dict(zip(string,map(lambda x:ord(x)-97,string)))
>>> toinclude
{'p':15,'y':24,'t':19,'h':7,'o':14,'n':13}
>>> locals().update(toinclude)
>>> p
15
```

you could also use the `string` library

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> string = 'python'
>>> toinclude = dict(zip(string,map(ascii_lowercase.index,string.lower())))
>>> toinclude
{'p':15,'y':24,'t':19,'h':7,'o':14,'n':13}
>>> locals().update(toinclude)
>>> y
24
```

**SIDENOTE**: the first method is a little bit slower but doesn't rely on any library, to make work the second method without any library use this:

```
>>> ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module `string` for a quick access to the characters of the alphabet via `ascii_lowercase` attribute, not mandatory but faster than write them by hand.

Your idea to turn each character of the string into a variable... is a bad programming pattern... for example what would happen if the string has 100 characters? Simply you spam the main scope with variables or you risk to overwrite other variables as well. Further, you need to create a string to be evaluated as a python command (or play around with `locals`/`globals`) which is usually an hazard. That's why I divided my answer into two parts:

Part 1: use a dictionary to stores the characters and indices

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

string = 'pyhton'

# get indices
mapper = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(ascii_lowercase)))
string_indices = map(mapper.get, string.lower())

# dictionary of chars-indices keys-values
string_dict = dict(zip(string, string_indices))
#{'p': 15, 'y': 24, 'h': 7, 't': 19, 'o': 14, 'n': 13}

print(*zip(*string_dict.items()))
#('p', 'y', 'h', 't', 'o', 'n') (15, 24, 7, 19, 14, 13)

# index of the h-character in python
print(string_dict['h'])
#7
```

Part 2: evaluation part with [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Notice: introduce a auxiliary variable, `chars`, to keep reference of the `tuple`. Its name can be modified to be sure to avoid conflicts.

```
# string statement for tuple evaluation
statement = 'chars = {} = {}'.format('('+', '.join(tuple(string))+')', tuple(string_dict.values()))
print(statement)
#chars = (p, y, h, t, o, n) = (15, 24, 7, 19, 14, 13)

# execute the statement
exec(statement, None, None)

# the tuples
print(chars)
#(15, 24, 7, 19, 14, 13)

# index of the h-character in python
print(h)
#7
```

With both parts you may have access to the data and the difference is quite minimal:
`string_dict['h']` VS `h` but the side-effects are big. I recommend to stop at part 1 and used part 2 as a theoretical exercise.

Answer (score 0):

exec/eval combination uses values from your first assignment:

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)

string = 'python'
newstring = ''
newvalues = ''

for i in string:
    newstring += i + ","
    newvalues += str(eval(i)) + ","

newstring = '(' + newstring[:-1] + ")" # (p,y,t,h,o,n)
newvalues = '(' + newvalues[:-1] + ")" # (15,24,19,7,14,13)

exec(newstring + " = " + newvalues)    # (p,y,t,h,o,n) = (15,24,19,7,14,13)
```

but new assignment can be avoided, you can use values directly using eval from the string:

```
string = 'python'

for i in string:
    print(eval(i))

# 15
# 24
# 19
# 7
# 14
# 13
```